# How to get formControlNames from form?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a form and there are 5 fields. There are 2 fields that are using **p-calendar**. I would like to get the **formControlName** of those fields. In simple words I want to store **"calendar1"** and **"calendar2"** inside of an array.

```
let myArray = ["calendar1", "calendar2"]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-ufvpop?file=app%2Fcalendar%2Fcalendar.component.ts)

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationFormGroup">
  <input formControlName = "username" placeholder = "username"/><br/>
  <input formControlName = "userlastname" placeholder = "userlastname"/><br/>
  <p-calendar  placeholder = "calendar1" formControlName = "calendar1"
hourFormat="24"></p-calendar><br/>
  <input type = "text" formControlName = "hobby" placeholder = "hobby"/><br/>
  <p-calendar placeholder="calendar2" formControlName = "calendar2"></p-calendar>
</form>
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have a form and there are 5 fields. There are 2 fields that are using p-calendar. I would like to get the formControlName of those fields. In simple words I want to store "calendar1" and "calendar2" inside of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the `ElementRef` of all calendar components used and get the `formControlName` attribute from it via `getAttribute()`.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModule, Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'  
})
export class CalendarComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
  value: Date;

  @ViewChildren(Calendar, { read: ElementRef })
  public calendars: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  public calendarNames: string[] = [];

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {} 

  registrationFormGroup = this._fb.group({
     username: [''],
     userlastname: [''],
     calendar1:[''],
     hobby: [''],
     calendar2:[''],
   });

   ngAfterViewInit()
   {
      this.calendarNames = this.calendars.map(({ nativeElement }) =>
      {
        return nativeElement.getAttribute('formControlname');
      });
   }
}
```

[**live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-bvrzy2)

Comment: Is there another way of getting the formControlName attribute without using getAttribute() ? Thank you

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but what do you mean by `angular way`, using getAttribute on a DOM Element is perfectly fine.

Comment: One quick question. Why do you pass { nativeElement } and not simply nativeElement  in your map function? Is that a typescript thing? Can you explain that please?

Comment: That's called javascript [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), it's a neat way to access object properties and use them directly as variables.

Comment: So in this case you used it to access properties of nativeElement?

Comment: In this case, it's used to access the property `nativeElement` of the `ElementRef` instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want get value of those formControl and add them to an array you only have to do this:

```
// your component and submit method
submitForm() {    
 this.myArray.push(this.registrationFormGroup.get('calendar1').value);
 this.myArray.push(this.registrationFormGroup.get('calendar2').value);
}
```

Comment: I want to get the actual formControlNames and store them inside of an array like this: let myArray = ["calendar1", "calendar2"]

Comment: There is not a method for do that, if you use any backend I recommended you add controls dynamically with this:  this.form.addControl("controlName", [Validators.required]) or simply create an array with the controls name in your component and add them when you create your form.  this.registrationFormGroup= this.fb.group({
 this.myArray[0], [Validators.required]})

Answer (score 0):

@progx

You could try the following, this is not an official way of doing it but I whipped up a solution.

If you have the following template you should try matching their formControlName to an id.

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationFormGroup">
  <input formControlName = "username" placeholder = "username"/><br/>
  <input formControlName = "userlastname" placeholder = "userlastname"/><br/>
  <p-calendar  id="calendar1" placeholder = "calendar1" formControlName = "calendar1"
hourFormat="24"></p-calendar><br/>
  <input type = "text" formControlName = "hobby" placeholder = "hobby"/><br/>
  <p-calendar id="calendar2" placeholder="calendar2" formControlName = "calendar2"></p-calendar>
</form>
```

This will allow you to query your template and do the following in your component.

```
let calendarFields: Array<string> = [];
let form = document.querySelector('form');

for(let i = 0 ; i < form.childElementCount; i++) {
  let child = form.children[i];
  // check for a form child element with the local name of p-calendar
  if(child.localName == 'p-calendar') {
      // This id will be the same as your formControlName
      calendarFields.push(child.id); 
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do in this way, if you *rely* on the FormControl Name,

```
var controls = Object.keys(this.registrationFormGroup.controls);
var calendarControlNames = controls.filter(x => {
     return x.match(/calendar/);
  })
console.log(calendarControlNames)
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  value: Date;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  registrationFormGroup = this._fb.group({
    username: [''],
    userlastname: [''],
    calendar1: [''],
    hobby: [''],
    calendar2: [''],
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    var controls = Object.keys(this.registrationFormGroup.controls);
    var calendarControlNames = controls.filter(x => {
      return x.match(/calendar/);
    })
    console.log(calendarControlNames)
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the name of the formControlNames are not always calendar (I have multiple calendar fields and their formControlNames are not calendar), so I cannot depend on return x.match(/calendar/); which is why I'm trying to target the fields by the tag name p-calendar